# "Critical error detected" in double import of Python module - Pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

basically I have an embedded interpreter in the main thread that has to be restarted by scratch. I got crash importing a module the second time
Here is the simplest code to reproduce ('datetime' just as example).

```
int main() {

    py::initialize_interpreter();
    py::module_::import("datetime");  //--> it works if I import modules, like 'sys', 'os'. 
    py::finalize_interpreter();

    py::initialize_interpreter();
    py::module_::import("datetime"); //--> crash here
    py::finalize_interpreter();
    return 0;
}
```

Running this gives:
**A breakpoint instruction (__debugbreak() statement or a similar call) was executed in test.exe.**

I am no expert in debugging, so if I forgot to report something helpful, let me know.
pybind from master branch, python 3.12, win10.

Comment: I don't know pybind at all but this is likely about numpy not being able to reinitialize, see e.g. https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/3112#issuecomment-881324839 and https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11925#issuecomment-419950086.

Comment: It does the same with almost any module, e.g. 'datetime'.

Comment: In that case I'd switch your example to that, because numpy is a very non-trivial piece here. It might prevent some wild goose chases.

Comment: I don't know if the same caveat that's quoted in my second link applies to built-in modules written in C: "_Some extensions may not work properly if their initialization routine is called more than once_". It might just be a different issue altogether.